# Data won't be inserted in the Database (Codeigniter3)

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, insert, codeigniter-3

My problem is that every time i click on submit button data wont be inserted in the database

the database configuration file is well configured but i don't know where the problem comes from

here are the files:
The controller:

```
class Store_items extends MX_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function create() {

        $this->load->module('site_security');
        $this->site_security->_make_sure_is_admin();

        $update_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $submit = $this->input->post('submit', TRUE);
        if ($submit == "Submit") {
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('item_title', 'Item Title', 'required|max_length[240]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('item_price', 'Item Price', 'required|numeric');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('was_price', 'Was Price', 'numeric');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('item_description', 'Item Description', 'required');
            if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == TRUE) {
                $data = $this->fetch_data_from_post();
                if (is_numeric($update_id)) {
                    //update
                    $this->_update($update_id, $data);
                    $flash_msg = "Le produit est mise à jour avec succes.";

                    $value = '<div class="alert alert-success" >' . $flash_msg . '</div>';
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('item', '$value');
                    redirect('store_items/create/' . $update_id);
                } else {
                    // insert new item
                    $this->_insert($data);
                    $update_id = $this->get_max(); //recupere l'id du nouveau produit

                    $flash_msg = "Le produit est ins avec succs.";
                    $value = '<div class="alert alert-success" >' . $flash_msg . '</div>';

                    $this->session->set_flashdata('item', '$value');
                    redirect('store_items/create/' . $update_id);//remember the flash data

                }
            }
        }

        if ((is_numeric($update_id)) && ($submit != "Submit")) {
            $data = $this->fetch_data_from_db($update_id);

        } else {
            $data = $this->fetch_data_from_post();
        }

        if ( ! is_numeric($update_id)) {
            $data['headline'] = "Add new";
        } else {
            $data['headline'] = "update";
        }

        $data['update_id'] = $update_id;
        $data['flash'] = $this->session->flashdata('item');
        $data['view_module'] = "store_items";
        $data['view_file'] = "create";
        $this->load->module('templates');
        $this->templates->admin($data);

    }

    function manage() {
        $this->load->module('site_security');
        $this->site_security->_make_sure_is_admin();
        //echo"Manage";
        $data['view_module'] = "store_items";
        $data['view_file'] = "manage";
        $this->load->module('templates');
        $this->templates->admin($data);

    }

    function fetch_data_from_post() {

        $data['item_title'] = $this->input->post('item_title', TRUE);
        $data['item_price'] = $this->input->post('item_price', TRUE);
        $data['was_price'] = $this->input->post('was_price', TRUE);
        $data['item_description'] = $this->input->post('item_description', TRUE);

        return $data;
    }

    function fetch_data_from_db($update_id) {
        $query = $this->get_where($update_id);
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data['item_title'] = $row->item_title;
            $data['item_url'] = $row->item_url;
            $data['item_price'] = $row->item_price;
            $data['item_description'] = $row->item_description;
            $data['big_pic'] = $row->big_pic;
            $data['small_pic'] = $row->small_pic;
            $data['was_price'] = $row->was_price;

        }
        if ( ! isset($data)) {
            $data = "";
        }

        return $data;

    }

    function get($order_by) {
        $this->load->model('mdl_store_items');
        $query = $this->mdl_store_items->get($order_by);

        return $query;
    }

    function get_with_limit($limit, $offset, $order_by) {
        $this->load->model('mdl_store_items');
        $query = $this->mdl_store_items->get_with_limit($limit, $offset, $order_by);

        return $query;
    }

    function get_where($id) {
        $this->load->model('mdl_store_items');
        $query = $this->mdl_store_items->get_where($id);

        return $query;
    }

    function get_where_custom($col, $value) {
        $this->load->model('mdl_store_items');
        $query = $this->mdl_store_items->get_where_custom($col, $value);

        return $query;
    }

    function _insert($data) {
        $this->load->model('mdl_store_items');
        $this->mdl_store_items->_insert($data);
    }

    function _update($id, $data) {
        $this->load->model('mdl_store_items');
        $this->mdl_store_items->_update($id, $data);
    }

    function _delete($id) {
        $this->load->model('mdl_store_items');
        $this->mdl_store_items->_delete($id);
    }

    function count_where($column, $value) {
        $this->load->model('mdl_store_items');
        $count = $this->mdl_store_items->count_where($column, $value);

        return $count;
    }

    function get_max() {
        $this->load->model('mdl_store_items');
        $max_id = $this->mdl_store_items->get_max();

        return $max_id;
    }

    function _custom_query($mysql_query) {
        $this->load->model('mdl_store_items');
        $query = $this->mdl_store_items->_custom_query($mysql_query);

        return $query;
    }
}
```

and here is the view file called Create.php where i will insert all the data 
to the database.

```
<h1> <? =$headline ?></h1>
<?= validation_errors("<p style='color: red;'>", "</p>") ?>

<?php
if (isset($flash)) {
    echo $flash;
}
?>
<div class="row-fluid sortable">
    <div class="box span12">
        <div class="box-header" data-original-title>
            <h2><i class="halflings-icon white edit"></i><span class="break"></span>Details du produit</h2>
            <div class="box-icon">
                <a href="#" class="btn-setting"><i class="halflings-icon white wrench"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="btn-minimize"><i class="halflings-icon white chevron-up"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="btn-close"><i class="halflings-icon white remove"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-content">
            <?php $form_location = base_url() . "store_items/create/" . $update_id; ?>
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="<?= $form_location ?>">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="typeahead">Nom du produit</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" class="span6" name="item_title" value="<?= $item_title ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="typeahead">Prix du produit</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" class="span1" name="item_price" value="<?= $item_price ?>">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="typeahead">Ancien prix</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" class="span1" name="was_price" value="<?= $was_price ?>">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group hidden-phone">
                        <label class="control-label" for="textarea2">Description du produit</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="textarea2" name="item_description">
                                    <?php echo $item_description; ?>
                                </textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-actions">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit">Save changes</button>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div><!--/span-->
</div><!--/row-->
```

Comment: You for sure need to learn the basics of debugging. Who can help you if you haven't tried to help yourself? You need to examine the values of your variables at different points in the code to determine what is happening.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I've put in some standard echos and print_r's into your create function that should help us determine where the error is occuring: https://pastebin.com/CnHy1X30 ... try it and report back with what you expected to get and what you got. Also, I would generally suggest not calling `$this->_insert` in the controller and just doing `$this->load->model('mdl_store_items'); $this->mdl_store_items->_insert($data);` its less redundancy. If you 100% want to do it your way, declare those functions as private in your controller, as they shouldn't  be viewable/reachable unless internally.

Comment: Well being a database related question which is using a model, it would be more helpful if you provided the code for that as well.

Comment: @Alex .. did you consider posting your commented answer as answer? Even if its not the full answer... you can edit it later when more info comes availabe from OP. Reviewed question.. moved to editing.

Comment: @ZF007 I did, but I don't feel like debugging practice is an answer - maybe it is... I'm not a rep hound anyways... if it helps it helps.

Comment: lol.. I raised it because its about kiddos overlooking answers in comments  ;-) And I did get it as triage review...

Comment: In CodeIgniter 3, `Mx_controller` is replaced with extends `CI_Controller`

Comment: @Avinash MX_Controller replaces CI_Controller as the OP is using HMVC.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == TRUE)
```

change `run($this)` to `run()`

Form_validation method `run()` Parameter

```
$group (string) -- The name of the validation group to run
```